# Incrementing a max value with leading zero format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

What would be the best way to increment a max value that will contain the leading zeroes? I have this query that works nearly perfectly, only that it doesn't keep the leading zeros. I also don't want to edit the data type for the column.

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(MAX(UniqueID), 5), RIGHT(MAX(UniqueID), 4) + 1)
FROM animal 
WHERE UniqueID LIKE 'MU19M%';
```

This returns: `MU19M51` but needs to be `MU19M0051` which is how all the other unique ID's are written in the column. I want to run this query so I can see what the next ID would be without inserting anything into the table for quality control. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Using a technique similar to `SELECT MAX(id) + 1` is usually a fairly poor way to generate a primary key

Comment: right(max(UniqueID),4)+1 is an implicit conversion to an integer to do the addition.  When a varchar is cast to an integer, it loses the leading zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FORMAT with format string 'D4' should do it:

```
SELECT 
  concat(
    left(max(UniqueID),5), 
    format(right(max(UniqueID),4)+1, 'D4')
  )
FROM animal 
WHERE UniqueID like 'MU19M%';
```

If your SQLserver doesn't have FORMAT (too old), you can `RIGHT(CONCAT('0000', number), 4)` instead:

```
SELECT 
  concat(
    left(max(UniqueID),5), 
    right(
      concat('0000', right(max(UniqueID),4)+1), 
      4
    )
  )
FROM animal 
WHERE UniqueID like 'MU19M%';
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I run those queries for some reason I get an incorrect syntax error near the keyword FROM. Any idea why that is? This is very helpful though thanks.

Comment: They were missing a closing bracket - now added

Answer (score 1):

But if using this value for a new key value, you should use a [sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of `max(id)+1`.  EG

```
create sequence MySequence start with 1 increment by 1
create table MyTable(Id varchar(20) default concat('MU19M', format( (next value for MySequence), 'D4')), a int)

insert into MyTable(a) values (1),(2)

select * from MyTable
```

which outputs:

```
Id                      a
--------------------    -----------
MU19M0001               1
MU19M0002               2
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't want to edit columns in my table though. I just want to see what the next string would be.